# Laravel CORS into framework v 9

Tags: php, laravel

Before Laravel 9 when I have error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/demo' from origin 'null' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource.
```

I must install fruitcake/laravel-cors ( https://www.positronx.io/how-to-enable-cors-in-laravel/  ).

In Laravel 9 I found information:

"Integrate Laravel CORS into framework
Dries Vints migrated the fruitcake/laravel-cors package into the Laravel framework:
The main reason is that we want to remove a circular dependency we rely on additionally to the fact that we eliminate another dependency of the skeleton.
All credits for the code go to @barryvdh of @fruitcake . Thanks for maintaining that package for so long!".

How can I make cors for example for url: api/list and api/profiles in new Laravel?

Answer (score 5):

In your `app/Http/Kernel.php` check that CORS middleware is present:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    ...
];
```

Then open your `config/cors.php`. It works exactly the same as `fruitcake/laravel-cors`:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Comment: it doesn't working errors come when u dd file post request or print_r()

Comment: It doesn't work because the path is ignored. You need to update the 'paths' => ['*'], to allow all paths.